# Transcode sound for H.264

Tags: flash, audio, stream

I have created an application to publish my webcam with H.264 format.

If I play my video with a RTMP player, the stream works correctly (video & sound).
If I play with a HLS player, the stream (video) works but there is no sound...

However, I have tried to publish my webcam with Flash Media Encoder software and the stream works correctly (video & sound).

Could you please tell my how to set my Microphone object in actionscript 3 in order to publish the sound for H.264 format ?

I have follow the standard functions :

mic = Microphone.getMicrophone();
...
nsOut.attachAudio (mic);
nsOut.publish ("streamName","live");

I have tried with SPEEX codec but doesn't work too.

Thanks.
Xavier

Comment: H.264 is an MPEG video codec and if with sound then use MPEG audio codec. Choose either MP3 or AAC. Microphone codecs like NellyMoser or Speex it wont work in a HLS system. Are you using a streaming server (like Wowza, Red5 or Adobe Media Server etc)? Because usually they allow options to transcode so you send in H264 with Nelly/Speex but they output H264 with AAC audio to outside connections. Only then can it be playable if the connection is via HLS system.

Comment: PS: Streaming servers are not my expertise. I just process data before or after the server is involved (if any) so hopefully someone will expand on the above comment or at least it gave you a clue...

Comment: do you have an example how to use Nelly or how to transcode the microphone to MP3 or AAC ?

Comment: Use Nelly the same way you set Speex as mic codec before in your code. As for AAC its not free to "encode" since you are benefiting from MPEG's R&D so you can buy a **[plugin from an MPEG contributor](http://www.mainconcept.com/products/plug-ins/plug-ins-for-adobe/aac-encoder-fmle.html)** and follow **[these instructions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashMediaLiveEncoder/3.0/Using/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11c104ba878-7fdf.html)**. You only get the MainConcept decoder free with Flash (ie: Netstream playback). Other people just consider Wowza (cheap) or Red5 (free). Google each of them.

Comment: I gonna check the MainConcerpt pluggin but it's for Flash Media Encoder or it can be call since a, actionscript code ?

Because when I check the website, it seems that's only for FME...

Comment: Yeah it's only for FME... You can't use it to encode within just AS3 code (no **.as** files to import etc). You checked the **[free demo plugin](http://downloads.mainconcept.com/mdl/mdl.php?downloads.mainconcept.com+AACEncoder)** (30-sec record limit). Also why not use built-in MP3 in transcoder. It's similar and already free in FME, right?

Comment: With FME, it works but in my case, I have to create a flash application which is ran via web browser.
If you have a tuto or example in AS3 to transcode the sound in MP3, i'll take it :)